# Using ALSA's function snd_pcm_writei can I free the sample buffer right away?

Tags: c++, c, linux, alsa

Using ALSA to play audio, after calling **snd__pcm__writei**, can I free the sound sample buffer right away or do I need to wait until the sound is finished playing before I can free the sample buffer?

For example:

```
unsigned short *buffer;

buffer = malloc(size of sample to play);
...load data into buffer...
snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buffer, size of sample)
free(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to find out would be to start writing backwards from the end of the buffer and see if you affect the audio playback.  If you do then you definitely can't free the buffer.  If it makes no difference then you can safely free the buffer as the sound card is not reading from that particular block of memory.

Comment: -1 this approach to answering a question (trial and error) is just wrong. It might happen to work on your setup but fail on a different version of the ALSA libraries, or might work with soft mixing but not direct hardware access, or vice versa. Answering the question requires reading the specification/documentation, or asking the developers what their intent is if they haven't written it clearly into the documentation.

Comment: @R..:  While i get your point, working things like this out for yourself is one of the most important things to learn about development, IMO.  It teaches you a lot about how to analyse a problem and solve.  Obviously, though, eMailing the developer and asking is the ideal thing to do.

Comment: I guess we just disagree. I think this is a common practice in development that's not something important to learn, but rather an important thing not to make a habit of. This sort of trial-and-error programming is an endless source of code rot - code that works when it's originally written on the exact OS/OS-version it was written for, and subsequently breaks when somebody upgrades things or tries running it on a different OS.